# Upload image from URL through Drive API

Tags: http, google-api, google-drive-api, postman

I'm using Postman to learn how to use the Google Drive API.

I'm trying to upload an API to an image that is in a URL. I'm using the multipart upload described in this [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload), but the example is not clear to me, I can upload a file with the metadata I'm passing, but the image of the URL I've placed is not being sent.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code for my request.

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: *
Authorization: [myToken]
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=test
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: [postmanToken]

--test
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "imageTest",
  "parents": ["1Ij0ZR8yrubkHQaT6tSQNgK6AhW4gbP49"]
}

--test
Content-Type: image/*

https://download.shutterstock.com/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTUzNjcwMzQ0NSwiayI6InBob3RvLzEwMDcwNjYwMjMvaHVnZS5qcGciLCJtIjoxLCJkIjoic2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrLW1lZGlhIn0sInR3UkJ0bDZNYUJNUXJ2azZlaE9MbTZlT2VBbyJd/shutterstock_1007066023.jpg
--test--
```

Comment: File cannot be directly uploaded to Google Drive using URL. And unfortunately, there are no APIs for achieving directly the situation. In order to upload the file from the URL, at first, it is required to download the file from URL and upload the file to Google Drive using Drive API. Or I think that you can create an API for achieving what you want using Google Apps Script, and you use the API from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be able to use Postman to upload a file.  Its going to have to read the file first and then send the file data in chunks.

All of the examples google has for this is using a programming language there is no samples of doing it directly with HTTP calls [file upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

If it did work you would be looking at something like this.  You are still going to need some language to read the file contents and add it to this.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
[[ Less interesting headers ... ]]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Length: 834

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text1"

text default
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text2"

aωb
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Content of a.txt.

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="a.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html><title>Content of a.html.</title>

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3"; filename="binary"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

aωb
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150--
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my friend! Basically what I need is to send an image to google drive through the API, I'm using Postman to understand how I'll do my HTTP request, because I'm using Node-Red to build an application, and there I have the javaScript language and some node making HTTP requests. I've read the Google Drive documentation several times but still can not understand how I can upload an image, can you guide me with something within the context I'm working on?

Comment: If your using javascript you should look into the Google apis js client library it should be able to handle the upload for you.  Doing this in raw http is not advisable